# Swift pages: Load remote image

Tags: swift, swift4, swift-playground, xcode9.3

I'm trying to load a remote image with the following code:

```
//:  ![Xcode icon](http://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/assets/elements/icons/128x128/xcode.png "Some hover text")
```

But when I switch to "Show rendered markup" I only see the "Xcode icon" text.

[image]

Any of you knows why the swift pages are not showing the image? or what do I need to do for the swift pages to show the images?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe playgrounds will not load remote image for you, only quickhelp using that format will..

To load an image download png you want to show, add it to your playground resources and load using:

```
//: ![Xcode icon](xcode.png)
```

Comment: That would work if you have the image in your playground. What about if you pulling the image remotely ?